# Using formic and regex to find all phone numbers on partition Python

Tags: python, regex, csv, glob

I'm trying to find all phone numbers in all csv files on my entire computer, regardless of formatting differences (within reason).  I'm looking to speed this up as much as possible and for code assistance in general (I'm just making this up as I go).  I switched to formic instead of glob and don't even know if I'm using it correctly (especially with Windows' stupid backslash-based filesystem).  For context, I have thousands of files, some with millions of phone numbers.

This is what I'm trying:

```
import csv
import re
from formic import FileSet

with open('MegaList.csv', 'wb') as out:
    seen = set()
    regex = re.compile(r'(\+?[2-9]\d{2}\)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4})')
    csv_files = FileSet(directory='C:\\', include='**\\*.csv')
    out_writer = csv.writer(out)
    out_writer.writerow([])
    for filename in csv_files:
        with open(filename, 'rbU') as ifile:
            read = csv.reader(ifile)
            try:  #some files have row return NULL byte, so skip errors
                for row in read:
                    for column in row:
                        s1 = column.strip()
                        if 9 < len(column) < 15: #does this make it faster or slower?
                            match = regex.search(s1)
                            if match:
                                canonical_phone = re.sub(r'\D', '', match.group(0))
                                if canonical_phone not in seen:
                                    seen.add(canonical_phone)
            except:
                pass
    for val in seen:
        out_writer.writerow([val])
```

Comment: Are you going for accuracy or speed? If you are going for accuracy, there is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phonenumbers

Comment: Well, I was definitely looking for more speed, but that's SUCH a great find for my (other) purposes!